# In warning messages, can multi-storey expressions be flattened?

Tags: output-formatting, output, command-line, free-wolfram-engine

I receive the following output in command line:

```
                               (2 I) t
Integrate::idiv: Integral of ------------ does not converge on {0, Infinity}.
                                  -2 Pi t
                             1 - E
```

Is there a way to flatten such outputs; i.e., tell the front-end not to use multi-storey form, but use only one-line form suitable for input?